# Scheduling difference manual execution vs Slurm srun/sbatch

Tags: cpu, scheduling, nice, slurm

***tl;dr*** A CPU intensive workload ignores the nice values of other processes only when started via Slurm sbatch/srun (not when manually started).

I am running a systemd service which periodically gathers hardware performance data. This service deploys *N* (number of cores) daemons which are all pinned to run on the one core that they are assigned to. To ensure that they are more or less scheduled when desired <sup>1</sup>, the service (and all its threads/daemons inherently) are started with a nice value of -20.

When running a cpu intensive task/benchmark like for example

```
stress --cpu $(nproc) --timeout 60s
```

all daemons of my service are able to perform their actions <sup>2</sup> within <200ms (which is fine).

However, when I submit the same stress test via Slurm sbatch/srun <sup>3</sup> my daemons are starved of the CPU. Instead of taking <200ms, the daemons are (as I assume) not scheduled and need several seconds to perform their actions (10-20x overhead increase).

The daemons are not limited by any other factors like I/O, memory, shared resources as they are only accessing hardware registers. There are no limitations regarding the cgroups. Autogrouping is disabled on this system.

*System: 2x AMD EPYC 7713 (64c), 256GB RAM; AlmaLinux8.4 with Kernel 4.18.0*

**Question:**

What is the difference in terms of scheduling between starting the stress test manually and via Slurm? Why does one not affect the scheduling of my daemons while the other starves them of the cpu?

---

<sup>1</sup> I am aware that this would be a real-time scheduling problem, but I want to avoid changing to a real-time scheduling policy if possible

<sup>2</sup> Primarily set/read hardware performance counters

<sup>3</sup> See the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash 
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --partition=ALL 
#SBATCH --nodelist=myNode 
#SBATCH --time=00:05:00  
stress --cpu $(nproc) --timeout 60s
```

Comment: You mention that "There are no limitations regarding the cgroups", so can I assume this means that SLURM is not configured with CGROUPS (e.g. you don't have ProctrackType=proctrack/cgroup or TaskPlugin=task/affinity,task/cgroup in your slurm.conf)?

Comment: What value is $(nproc) giving in the SLURM batch script?  How many of those batch jobs are you submitting at one time?  If $(nproc) is returning 1, then I'm assuming you are submitting 128 copies of the batch job.  If $(nproc) is returning 128 (2 x 64 cores (or maybe even 256 if hardware threading is on)), then I'm assuming you are submitting 1 copy of the batch job.

Comment: The slurm.conf contains neither ProctrackType=proctrack/cgroup nor any TaskPlugin. The administrator confirmed that Slurm is not set up with cgroups. $(nproc) returns 256 and I am only submitting one job with ntasks=1.

Comment: For a given period, do all of the daemons (128 or 256 of them), show this 10 to 20 times overhead increase?  You mention that your daemons are not limited by I/O, however they are likely writing the gathered performance data somewhere (e.g. disk), it would be interesting to know if the daemons do this efficiently (e.g. gather all data then write to log, or write to log after every piece of data if obtained).

Comment: I am using the [LIKWID](https://github.com/RRZE-HPC/likwid) library to access hardware performance counters for which I spawn $(nproc) daemons (which inherit the -20 nice value). I can't determine the individual overhead of each daemon as I am only calling perfmon_switchActiveGroup() to instruct all daemons which events are to be measured next. This call returns when all daemons executed their actions (reading the hardware counters and setting new ones). The results are only read back after each measurement period (thus not contributing to the overhead) and are held in memory.

Comment: Can you try using "stress --cpu 1 --timeout 60s" (i.e. "1" instead of "$(nproc)") in your SLURM batch file and submitting 256 batch jobs?  You can use the sbatch "--array=0-255" parameter to simplify the submission.

Comment: You could put something like the following in your SLURM job script, which will give you an idea if there is any CPU affinity taking place:  "taskset -c -p $(cut -d ' ' -f 4 /proc/self/stat)".